# Accelerate an object in a current-carrying coil

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electromagnetism, kinematics, experimental-physics, linear-motion

I'm currently trying to come up with some concept ideas for a physics game / riddle. The player has to get an object from one side of a horizontal, current-carrying coil to the other end of the coil where it can drop down a chute. This item would be a small ball (magnetic / ferrous / a magnet if needed). The catch is that by default, when the item is put in to the coil, it should be accelerated back towards the player. The player would then realise that they need to flip the polarity of the current within the coil to change the direction of the magnetic field of the coil so that the object is then accelerated down the coil towards the chute. How would I make this happen and what physics principles would it use / require? TIA.

Comment: Perhaps a DPDT switch?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE! Please visit the [tour] page to know more about the type of questions that can be asked here. The question, in its current form, does not have enough details in it. Please make it more specific by [edit]ing the question to include what you have already tried out and any other helpful detail.

Comment: Magnetic fields can cancel. I'd use that to attract metal to a magnet where player does not want it, and cancel it with an electromagnet.

Comment: Thanks @Abel . This gives me a bunch of new ideas.